# How to make wire frame like square grid but not the type of connected nodes?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm designing the styles of human body OBJ's wire frame, and I want to make the wire frame like the image following. 
Following, there are codes how I create wire frame and images, including how does it looks like and how I want it to look like.

```
// child is the human body's OBJ, is type of THREE.Mesh.
const geo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(child.geometry)
const mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat)
child.add(wireframe)
```

[image: Edit]

Appearance for now
[image: Appearance now]

Expected appearance
[image: Expected appearance]

Comment: use a 3d modeling software? this is unrelated to programming afaict.

Comment: Is there any mathematical calculations which can make wireframes into square or create a squared wireframes to cover the model?

Comment: `THREE.WireframeGeometry` will always give you triangles. Based on your image, your mesh does not have a grid-like pattern anyway, so you would be unable to use the existing geometry. You will need to find a way to create this grid structure, and define it as a new geometry.

Comment: @TheJim01
You're right. I have had same comment to my leader. If there's not any solutions here. I think I will try to create a squared grid texture then put it into envMap.

Comment: Fix : `envMap -> *{THREE.Mesh}.map`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'

function createLinesTexture() {
  const width = 200
  const height = 200
  const color = new THREE.Color(0x05cfe8)
  const size = width * height
  const data = new Uint8Array(3 * size)

  const r = Math.floor(color.r * 255)
  const g = Math.floor(color.g * 255)
  const b = Math.floor(color.b * 255)

  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const stride = i * 3
    // Here is the tips to change how color patterns mapping
    if ((i / 3) % 4 === 0) {
      data[stride] = r
      data[stride + 1] = g
      data[stride + 2] = b
    } else {
      data[stride] = 255
      data[stride + 1] = 255
      data[stride + 2] = 255
    }
  }

  // used the buffer to create a DataTexture

  const texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, width, height, THREE.RGBFormat)
  return texture
}
```